# round ImageButton full width background image

Tags: android, image, imagebutton

I am trying to set a backgroundimage to my `ImageButton`. The `ImageButton` should be full filled. Currently it looks like:

[image]

`ImageButton`

```
<ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imgBtn_OpenUserPicture"
                    android:layout_width="96dp"
                    android:layout_height="96dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_camera"
                    android:background="@drawable/round_imagebutton"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:tint="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:padding="20dp"/>
```

`@drawable/round_imagebutton`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
        <corners android:radius="90dp" />
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#FFF"
            />
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

One problem could be the `padding of 20dp`. After removing it, the problem was the same. I think I have to set the image as the background of the shape. But how can I set the image dynamically - captured by the camera - to the shape background?

Comment: You can use Glide library to make image rounded

Comment: Removed the `rounding` tag, which is to do with numerical rounding (3.1415926535 -> 3.14).

Answer (score 1):

Use scale type as fit center.

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

Comment: Also add scaleType as fit center

Comment: I changed the scaleType from `centerCrop` to `fitCenter`

Comment: also check for fitXY.I think your problem will solve using scaleType.

Answer (score 1):

There are Two way

1# Use rounded image instead of rectangle to set src

2# use this link instead of ImageButton

https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

Comment: Is there any possiblity to set an inner padding?

Comment: Not possible because you want to set a rectangle image in circle. use rounded image  instead of rectangle and it's solve your issue.